# Latex: Using Minted package - how do I make it wrap the text (linebreaks=true)

Tags: syntax, latex, pygments

Im using the `Pygments` for a lot of things, and I'd like to also use this in my latex report. I found the package `Minted` which interacts with Pygments, but some of the comments and some of the code overflows the right margin. I have used lstlistings' `breaklines=true` in the past, but I don't see a way to get that functionality using the Minted package, any ideas?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}  
\usepackage{fancyvrb}  
\usepackage{minted}  

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[mathescape,
 linenos,
 numbersep=5pt,
 frame=single,
 numbersep=5pt,
 xleftmargin=0,
 ]{python}
class Run(BaseModel):
 """
 Run: unique Tool and multiple Inputs
 Status:
  Running => jobs are pending or runing and not all jobs have been completed
  Paused => workers querying for 'Running' Runs won't get this Run until we change status again
  Done => all jobs have completed and have a result_status = 'Done'
  Incomplete => No results (inputs) have been associated with the Run
 """ 
 name = models.CharField(max_length = 150,
  unique=True)
 tool = models.ForeignKey('Tool')
 tags = models.ManyToManyField(RunTag, related_name="model_set")
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

<del>Unfortunately, there’s no solution within `minted` at the moment or for the foreseeable future, sorry. Implementing the `breaklines` feature is quite difficult. Using `listings` instead may be your best solution here.</del>

Minted now has a `breaklines` option.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer Konrad.
In spite of this, I was so satisfied with the results minted produced, that I wasn't too bothered by having to double-check the output.

Comment: do you currently have any activities in implementing a `breaklines` feature in minted?

Comment: I just want to repeat @eckes question

Comment: @Raubi I’m no longer the maintainer of `minted` since I lacked both the time and the LaTeX skills for it. It’s currently being developed by [Geoffrey Poore](https://github.com/gpoore/minted). He *does* intent to implement this feature, but I don’t know a timeline. [There is a solution, however](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112573/42), but it requires some fiddling.

Comment: `breaklines` is implemented now.

Comment: It doesn't appear to work in conjunction with the `obeytabs` option.

Comment: breaklines is great, but it doesn't break words

Comment: How do you use it, then?

Comment: Can it be configured not to add arrows at the start of each new line?

Comment: @user2023370 See [the documentation](https://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf):  “To customize
the line continuation symbols, use `breaksymbolleft` and `breaksymbolright`. […] To have no symbol, simply set `breaksymbolleft` to an empty string (“`=`,” or “`={}`”).”

Answer (score 20):

Minted 2.0 (just released) does line breaking if you give it the `breaklines` option:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}  
\usepackage{fancyvrb}  
\usepackage{minted}  

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[%
 breaklines,
 mathescape,
 linenos,
 numbersep=5pt,
 frame=single,
 numbersep=5pt,
 xleftmargin=0pt,
 ]{python}
class Run(BaseModel):
 "''
 Run: unique Tool and multiple Inputs
 Status:
  Running => jobs are pending or runing and not all jobs have been completed
  Paused => workers querying for 'Running' Runs won't get this Run until we change status again
  Done => all jobs have completed and have a result_status = 'Done'
  Incomplete => No results (inputs) have been associated with the Run
 "'' 
 name = models.CharField(max_length = 150,
  unique=True)
 tool = models.ForeignKey('Tool')
 tags = models.ManyToManyField(RunTag, related_name=''model_set'')
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

There are also various related options to control how the presence of a line break is indicated  in the output. See section 6.3 in the [minted](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at `texments` as it is for using the Pygments highlighter in LaTeX.
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/texments/

Comment: I've taken a look at it, but it didn't solve my problem, simply did the same. I may just have to do this all by hand then..